# Print Arabic Text - Right to Left

Tags: css, printing

In print page, I am passing css: direction: rtl to see arabic properly.

But while, printing all other css styles gets applied but direction: rtl is not working and prints normal left to right texts of Arabic.

Here is the [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/853q8/)

Here is the codes

```
<div class="formBLock" style="padding-top:0px;">

        <div class="formCon CaseDetailsButton">
            <div class="divbtn">
                <a class="btn more2" href="/ClientInquiry/ar/CaseInquiry">الرجوع </a>
            </div>
            <div class="divbtn">
                            <input type="button" id="btnPrint" class="btn more2" value="طباعة "/>   
             </div>
        </div>

               <div id="dvPrint">
                    <div style="border:1px black solid;width:90%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;float:right;margin-top:10px;">
                            <div style="border-bottom:1px black solid;float:right;margin-top: 10px;width: 100%;">
                                <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%; font-weight:bold;"> تم استلام طلبكم : الاستعلام عن تقرير الحادث</span>
                            </div>  
                            <div style="border-bottom:1px black solid;float:right;margin-top: 10px;width: 100%;">
                                <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%;">شكرا لاستخدامكم نظام شركة نجم للاستعلام </span><br />
                                <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%;">المعلومات أدناه توضح الوضع الحالي لمستندات الحادث</span>
                            </div>   
                            <div style="border:1px solid black;width:90%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;height:200px;float:right;margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div style="float:right;width:30%;">
                                    <div style="height:50px;border-bottom:1px solid black;text-align:center;border-left:1px solid #000000">
                                        <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%; margin-top:7%;">بيانات الحادث</span>
                                    </div>   
                                    <div style="height:150px;text-align:center;border-left:1px solid #000000">
                                        <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%; margin-top:30%;">حالة إرسال المستندات</span>
                                    </div>   
                                </div>
                                <div style="height:200px;width:33.3%;margin-top:0px;float:right;border-left:1px solid #000000">
                                    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:50px;text-align:center;">
                                        <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%; margin-top:6%;">رقم الحالة</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:50px;text-align:center;">
                                        <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%; margin-top:6%;">حالة الإرسال</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="height:100px;width:36.3%;margin-top:0px;float:right;">
                                    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:50px;">
                                        <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%; margin-top:6%;">RD21031414</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:50px;">
                                           <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%; margin-top:6%;">&nbsp;قيد المعالجة من شركة نجم</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div style="border-top:1px solid black;float:right;margin-top: 10px;width: 100%;">
                                <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%; font-weight:bold;">شركة نجم لخدمات التأمين</span>
                                <span style="color: #8F8E8E;float: right;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 15px;font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 1px;vertical-align: middle;width: 90%;">لمزيد من المعلومات يرجى الاتصال بـ 920000460 كما يمكنك زيارة 
                                    <a href="CaseFooterLink" target="_blank">Site.sa</a>
                                    أو الفرع الأقرب لشركة نجم 
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
        <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
         var ObjdvPrint = $("#dvPrint");
         window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = ObjdvPrint.html();
         window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus()
         window.frames["print_frame"].window.print()
         return false;
     });
 });
```

Comment: I have print css in body tag and arabic content in p tag.. thats it in code which displays right to left arabic but in print, other classes/styles gets affects but not direction: rtl

Comment: Arabic text doesn’t even normally need any direction setting, since Arabic letters have inherent right-to-left directionality. You need to show an actual testable example, preferably a minimal HTML+CSS (or XML+CSS) document that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Link to JS fiddler is: http://jsfiddle.net/853q8/

Comment: http://www.katpatuka.org/pub/doc/content-language/ar.htm

Comment: Hope above link help you all... Thanks

Comment: The question itself should contain sufficient information for seeing what the problem is and reconstructing it. And in the jsfiddle, text runs right to left.

Comment: Yes, so by clicking on button in js fiddle, it will print left to right instead of right to left.

Comment: You seem to be saying that the problem is that when you click on the print button (طباعة) on the page, the data gets printed so that texts are *left-aligned*. The writing direction is correct (right to left), but text lines end at the left edge of each element, instead of starting at the right edge. Is *this* the problem? Please clarify this by editing the question itself.

Comment: Yes, true. Thats the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, as per the comments, that when a print button is used, the data printed has text aligned to the left, not right (the writing direction is not the issue).

The reason is that the printing is performed this way:

```
var ObjdvPrint = $("#dvPrint");
window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = ObjdvPrint.html();
window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus()
window.frames["print_frame"].window.print()
```

So a frame is created, containing only an element (with `id="dvPrint"`) of the original document. This element has various inline styles (in `style` attributes), but nothing that would set the horizontal alignment, so the default `text-align: left` is applied. Whatever is set on the `body` element of the original document has no impact.

The fix is to set the alignment on the content of that element, in a manner that is retained when the frame is created. Since you are using `innerHTML`, it does not help to set things on that element itself. But in this case, the content of that element is a single inner `div` element, so it helps to set the alignment to it:

```
<div id="dvPrint">
   <div dir="rtl" style="...">
```

You could alternatively just add `text-align: right` in the content of the `style` attribute of the inner element. But `dir="rtl"` by definition sets the horizontal alignment (`text-align: right`), among other things. It also sets the overall writing directionality, which is normally not necessary, but a good precaution against a) browser bugs and b) possible mix of e.g. Arabic and Latin characters in some future version of the document.

Comment: Thanks, I did same way by passing whole html and with proper css as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

By using below meta it will work.

http://www.katpatuka.org/pub/doc/content-language/ar.htm

Thanks everyone for help !!!?

Comment: Declaring character encoding and content language are useful things to do, but neither of them has anything to do with the problem asked, the writing direction. A link to a live page is never a sufficient answer. And this page, from 2002, itself declares its character encoding wrong (in HTTP headers, which trumps all `meta` tags, it says it’s in ISO-8859-9 encoding (ISO Latin/Turkish, not supporting any Arabic letters at all).

Comment: Thanks, Please suggest other way to achieve my problem solution if you have.